# cant start windows 7 after ubuntu dual boot upgraed

Tags: 12.04, 14.04, grub2, windows-7, wubi

I was running dual boot win 7/64 - Ubuntu 12.04 installed via Wubi. After upgrading Ubuntu to 14.04, I can't login to windows 7, the GRUB menu loads, but its stuck on loading windows screen.

Initially, I wasn't able to login to Ubuntu either, but this thread helped me http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2217829, I followed the hakuna_matata's advice on changing GRUB2 boot enry.

After running boot-repair, I got the following http://paste.ubuntu.com/9647860/, while the repair said it was successful, my problem remained.

I welcome even rough hints, as I'm not sure how to move from this point

Comment: boot-repair reported that it fixed the problem, but I'm still not able to login, so technically speaking it didn't fail, better say didn't resolve my boot problem.

Comment: tl;dr If you can't boot Windows, use a Windows repair CD or Install DVD to repair it. Are you sure it's a GRUB menu loading, because you have a Wubi install - and there is no Windows entry in your GRUB menu. It's probably your Windows Boot Manager. Boot-repair doesn't fix Wubi installs or Windows. The best it can do is install a Windows style bootloader which likely wasn't your problem in the first place. You can try hitting the F8 key after the BIOS menu appears - or after selecting Windows in the boot manager, that may also give you some recovery options.

Answer (score -1):

Ordinarily boot repair solves issues of simple grub issues.  That report you posted revealed a problem I've never seen before, or even heard mention of.  I refer to line 731 which reads, "Partition 4 does not start on physical sector boundary."  The good news is that theoretically this may be something you can fix by yourself using [gparted](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/gparted/).  It may be as simple as deleting partitions 5 and 6 and then deleting partition 4 as well.  After you do all that you can install Ubuntu again but this time in more traditional manner that should not be prone to these problems.

Comment: thanks, I will give this a go, and report back how it went

Comment: You don't delete partitions to fix a Wubi problem. You don't delete partitions because they don't start on a physical sector boundary.

Answer (score -1):

Ubuntu's grub can't make an entry for Windows and that's why grub only boots Ubuntu 
use the following commands:

```
sudo update-grub
sudo reboot
```